How to add a sqlite plugin file (.so) to an Android app?
I'm developing an Android app that will need to load a self compiled sqlite plugin (libsimple). The compiled plugin is a .so file.
sqlite-android can load such file as plugin. But I'm new to Android development and don't know how to get the file properly loaded.
Currerently, I'm putting compiled plugin in jniLibs.
app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main/
│  │  ├─ jniLibs/
│  │  │  ├─ x86_64/
│  │  │  │  ├─libsimple.so
│  │  │  ├─ arm64_v8a/
│  │  │  │  ├─libsimple.so

The built apk does contain the files.
apk-debug.apk/
├─ lib/
│  ├─ x86_64/
│  │  ├─libsimple.so
│  ├─ arm64_v8a/
│  │  ├─libsimple.so

The path defined in code is like following:
private val libsimplePath = "${context.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir}/libsimple.so"

However when running the app in Android studio with API 35, the returned path is like
data/app/~~W0ZleGXEDPvGfIKN22O5Ow==/com.hal9000com.picfinder-eadN36R50XdAo86g8fxllN==/lib/x86_64/libsimple.so

and following test code will return false. The plugin load will fail too.
fun isPathReadable(path: String): Boolean {
    val file = File(path)
    return file.canRead()
}

But when I upload the .so file and select it using file picker, It will get path like
/data/user/0/com.hal9000com.picfinder/cache/libsimple.so

and the plugin will work.
Questioning ChatGPT returns no good and I've tried adding
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

to AndroidManifest.xml, but nothing changes.
The extension loading part of the code is as following.
import io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseConfiguration
import io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCustomExtension

private val libsimplePath = "${context.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir}/libsimple.so"
private val cfg = SQLiteDatabaseConfiguration(":memory:", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
val ext = SQLiteCustomExtension(libsimplePath, null)
cfg.customExtensions.add(ext)
private val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(cfg, null, null)

A path to .so file is required as defined in sqlite-android source code.
public final class SQLiteCustomExtension {

    public final String path;
    public final String entryPoint;

    /**
     * Creates a SQLite extension description.
     *
     * @param path       path to the loadable extension shared library
     *                   e.g. "/data/data/(package)/lib/libSqliteICU.so"
     * @param entryPoint extension entry point (optional)
     *                   e.g. "sqlite3_icu_init"
     */
    public SQLiteCustomExtension(String path, String entryPoint) {
        if (path == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null path");
        }
        this.path = path;
        this.entryPoint = entryPoint;
    }
}


Found a solution, the .so files should be placed in assets folder and copied when the app startup.
fun copyAssetToInternalStorage(context: Context, assetFileName: String,saveName:String): String? {
    val file = File(context.filesDir, saveName)
    try {
        context.assets.open(assetFileName).use { inputStream ->
            FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return file.absolutePath
}

Then the path can be accessed.
